# What is Thymeleaf cacheable template?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am learning Thymeleaf and don't understand what are cacheable templates.
Can you sb explain me what they are and usage?
Thanx

Answer (score 6):

By default, cache is enabled for thymeleaf, therefore all pages are cached.

Thymeleaf template engine will store parsed templates before processing them, so that if there are changes, it is possible to see those only after re-reading/parsing the files again (e.g. redeploy, restart).

This is actually very convenient, specially in heavy web application(many pages with different sizes), as otherwise for every single change it will re-read all pages (which is simple input/output operations - costing time), though the most of the pages would never be changed.

You can disable the cache explicitly when configuring template engine

`templateResolver.setCacheable(false);`

With disabled cache, after modifying thymeleaf pages you can just reload the page in the web browser and see the changes, so for every single change thymeleaf will parse the template and load into the application immediately. Again, it will re-load all pages from your application, not the single one which has been changed.

Also it is possible to clear cache for single template by

`templateEngine.clearTemplateCacheFor("/test");`

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your response. If you don't mind and have some time, could you show me some more documentation or page about Thyemeleaf caching? I really want to know more about this. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are only parsed once, when they’re first used, and the results
of that parse are cached for subsequent use. This is a great feature for production,
as it prevents redundant template parsing on each request and thus improves
performance. 
That feature is not so awesome at development time, however. Let’s say you fire
up your application and hit the taco design page and decide to make a few changes
to it. When you refresh your web browser, you’ll still be shown the original version.
The only way you can see your changes is to restart the application, which is quite
inconvenient.
There’s a way to disable caching. All you need to do is set a templateappropriate caching property to false
Properties to enable/disable template caching:
[image]

All of these properties are set to true to enable caching. You can disable
caching for your chosen template engine by setting its cache property to false. For
example, to disable Thymeleaf caching, add the following line in **application.properties**: